# Converting a binary value from the registry to a string in VB 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to pull a value from the registry that is in binary format and converting it into a string and entering it into a text box.  When I run my code the text box is empty.  I have checked the registry and there is a binary value there as well as checking with code in VB.  Below is my code for getting the value and converting it and adding it to a text box.

```
    Dim LANDeskVirus As String = CStr(My.Computer.Registry.GetValue _
        ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\LANDesk\ManagementSuite\WinClient\Antivirus", _
        "PatternFileDate", Nothing))

    Dim LANDeskVirusDefintion As String = Convert.ToString(LANDeskVirus)
    Dim BinaryText As String = LANDeskVirusDefintion
    Dim Characters As String = Regex.Replace(BinaryText, "[^01]", "")
    Dim ByteArray((Characters.Length / 8) - 1) As Byte
    For Index As Integer = 0 To ByteArray.Length - 1
        ByteArray(Index) = Convert.ToByte(Characters.Substring(Index * 8, 8), 2)
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = (ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(ByteArray))
```

Comment: Try setting a break point on your variables when you run the solution it will break on it. Then press F11 and step through to make sure you are getting what you need. If your variables are empty, then you are not getting what you need first...PS a string is already in binary...

Answer (score 1):

Look at the registry with Regedt32.exe. If the Type of that key value is REG_SZ, then it is a string and you can just assign it to the text box directly.

```
TextBox1.Text = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue _
    ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\LANDesk\ManagementSuite\WinClient\Antivirus", _
    "PatternFileDate", Nothing)
```

If it is something like REG_DWORD, then you can convert it to a string and then assign it to the text box, something like this:

```
TextBox1.Text = CStr(My.Computer.Registry.GetValue _
    ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\LANDesk\ManagementSuite\WinClient\Antivirus", _
    "PatternFileDate", Nothing))
```

With a REG_BINARY value with 8 bytes, you can probably get the date like this. (You might need to use .FromBinary instead of .FromFileTime)

```
dim b() as byte
b = CStr(My.Computer.Registry.GetValue _
        ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\LANDesk\ManagementSuite\WinClient\Antivirus", _
        "PatternFileDate", Nothing))
TextBox1.Text = DateTime.FromFileTime(BitConverter.ToUInt64(b, 0)).ToString
```

Comment: The registry keys that im trying to pull are REG_BINARY and the value its holding is suppose to be a date that I would need to show in normal date format mm/dd/yyyy so how would i pull those and values and enter it into a text box.

Comment: A REG_BINARY value can be read into a byte array. This may contain a date object, or a 3-byte date in y-m-d (or some other form). If it's the 3-byte date, you have to add 1970 to the year.

Comment: How would I do that then because I tried setting it up in a byte array and im not getting any info in the text box, so not sure what im doing wrong

Comment: I edited the answer and added something that will work for most 8-byte REG_BINARY dates.

Comment: Thank you, i was able to pull the info and add it to a text box.  The only thing now is it shows this - 8/16/0020 4:43:27 AM  when according to the program im pulling it from it should be 1/22/2013 3:42.  So not sure if the program is pulling the wrong numbers or the registry key is not right

Comment: Try DateTime.FromBinary, or you might try adding the integer value `BitConverter.ToUInt64(b, 0)` to 1/1/1970 in seconds or milliseconds: `dateadd(DateInterval.Second, BitConverter.ToUInt64(b, 0)/1000, "1/1/1970")`. There's no standard on binary dates in the registry, so you might check the app documentation.